# Prove that For every two sets, only one can be an element of the other

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show that if X $\in$ Y then Y$\notin$X or if $Y\in$X then X$\notin$Y.

Here's what I think by wikipedia
Let X and Y be sets. Then apply the axiom of regularity to the set {X,Y}. We see there must be an element of {X,Y} which is also disjoint from it. It must be either X or Y. By the definition of disjoint then, we must have either Y is not an element of {X,Y} or X is not an element of {X,Y}.

Next I think I need to show that if Y $\notin${X,Y}, then Y$\notin$X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you have to apply the axiom of regularity to $\{X,Y\}$.

Assume that $X\in Y$ and $Y\in X$. Then
$$Y\in\{X,Y\}\cap X$$
and
$$X\in\{X,Y\}\cap Y$$
That is, the set $\{X,Y\}$ is not disjoint with $X$ or $Y$, and that contradicts the axiom.

Comment: How do you know $X$ $\in$ $Y$ $\Rightarrow$ $Y$ $\in$ $\{X$,$Y\}$ $\cap$ $X$? and what does $\{X$,$Y\}$ $\cap$ $X$? equal? I'm guessing $\{X$,$Y\}$ $\cap$ $X$? equals $X$.

Comment: How do you know $Y$ $\in$ $\{X,Y\}$ $\cap$ $X$? @ajotatxe

Comment: For example, $X\in\{X,Y\}\cap Y$ because **a)** $X\in\{X,Y\}$ (obvious) and **b)** $X\in Y$ (assumption).